# MySQL Calculate Percentage within the same Column

Tags: mysql

On the table below, how would I calculate what percentage is the Food Cost on the Total Cost for each customer?
Looking to multiply "Food Cost" by 100, then divide by "Total Cost". Customer 1 would return 39.5 for example.

```
+------------+------------+--------+
| customerId |  category  | total  |
+------------+------------+--------+
|          1 | Food Cost  |  65031 |
|          1 | Total Cost | 164637 |
|          2 | Food Cost  |  72031 |
|          2 | Total Cost | 264637 |
+------------+------------+--------+


SELECT round(total * 100 / (SELECT total FROM table where category = "Total 
Cost" and customerId = 1), 2) as Total FROM table where category = "Food 
Cost" and customerId = 1;
```

This will give me the result I need for customer 1 but if I want to return both customers I will need to remove the customerId="" and that will return a MySQL error "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more that 1 row".

Comment: Wait...your table already is storing the total cost?  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation here to obtain the food and total cost records for each customer:

```
SELECT
    customerId,
    100.0 * MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'Food Cost' THEN total END) /
    MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'Total Cost' THEN total END) AS percentage
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY customerId;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this

```
SELECT ROUND(food.total * 100 / total.total, 1) AS 'Food Total'
FROM table AS food 
INNER JOIN table as total on food.customerId = total.customerId
WHERE food.category = 'Food Cost'
AND total.category = 'Total Cost';
```